# Why doesn't Search return anything?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I don't get any results regardless of what I type into the search box.

Comment: me too. Same with tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that -- full text indexing wasn't working on this database for some reason. I rebuilt the indexes and it seems better now.

Comment: Thanks, it works.